# Models converging with different versions of lme4

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I'm working through [Page Piccinini's R course](https://pagepiccinini.com/r-course/lesson-6-part-1-linear-mixed-effects-models/) and currently at lesson 6 on MLEMs. On occasion, I get different responses in the console than what Page Piccinini is presenting as her output. This leads me to ask:

Is it plausible (or maybe even normal and to be expected) that later versions of lme4 can converge a model that earlier versions of lme4 had issues with?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, **lme4** has changed the default optimization algorithms recently that may lead to the differences you observe.

Such changes are made because in most datasets they produce better results, but there can be cases that the old algorithms are better.

Comment: +1 For an example of earlier defaults working better, see [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/400479/28500).